# Android java.lang.NullPointerException during fragments switching

Tags: android, listview, parse-platform, adapter

i have a main activity with two tabs. each tab opens a fragment.
the problem occurs if i switch the tabs multiple times. the exception below occurs.

```
08-27 23:17:44.692: E/AndroidRuntime(28942): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-27 23:17:44.692: E/AndroidRuntime(28942): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-27 23:17:44.692: E/AndroidRuntime(28942):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.from(LayoutInflater.java:210)
08-27 23:17:44.692: E/AndroidRuntime(28942):    at android.view.View.inflate(View.java:16234)
08-27 23:17:44.692: E/AndroidRuntime(28942):    at mobi.liveplus.devplus.FenceOffersAdapter.getItemView(FenceOffersAdapter.java:44)
08-27 23:17:44.692: E/AndroidRuntime(28942):    at com.parse.ParseQueryAdapter.getView(ParseQueryAdapter.java:546)
08-27 23:17:44.692: E/AndroidRuntime(28942):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2465)
08-27 23:17:44.692: E/AndroidRuntime(28942):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1775)
08-27 23:17:44.692: E/AndroidRuntime(28942):    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:678)
08-27 23:17:44.692: E/AndroidRuntime(28942):    at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:739)
08-27 23:17:44.692: E/AndroidRuntime(28942):    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1614)
08-27 23:17:44.692: E/AndroidRuntime(28942):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2300)
08-27 23:17:44.692: E/AndroidRuntime(28942):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13856)
08-27 23:17:44.692: E/AndroidRuntime(28942):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4424)
08-27 23:17:44.692: E/AndroidRuntime(28942):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1655)
08-27 23:17:44.692: E/AndroidRuntime(28942):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1644)
08-27 23:17:44.692: E/AndroidRuntime(28942):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1428)
08-27 23:17:44.692: E/AndroidRuntime(28942):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13856)
08-27 23:17:44.692: E/AndroidRuntime(28942):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4424)
08-27 23:17:44.692: E/AndroidRuntime(28942):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
08-27 23:17:44.692: E/AndroidRuntime(28942):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13856)
08-27 23:17:44.692: E/AndroidRuntime(28942):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4424)
08-27 23:17:44.692: E/AndroidRuntime(28942):    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:690)
08-27 23:17:44.692: E/AndroidRuntime(28942):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13856)
08-27 23:17:44.692: E/AndroidRuntime(28942):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4424)
08-27 23:17:44.692: E/AndroidRuntime(28942):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
08-27 23:17:44.692: E/AndroidRuntime(28942):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13856)
08-27 23:17:44.692: E/AndroidRuntime(28942):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4424)
08-27 23:17:44.692: E/AndroidRuntime(28942):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1655)
08-27 23:17:44.692: E/AndroidRuntime(28942):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1513)
08-27 23:17:44.692: E/AndroidRuntime(28942):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1426)
08-27 23:17:44.692: E/AndroidRuntime(28942):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13856)
08-27 23:17:44.692: E/AndroidRuntime(28942):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4424)
08-27 23:17:44.692: E/AndroidRuntime(28942):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
08-27 23:17:44.692: E/AndroidRuntime(28942):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13856)
08-27 23:17:44.692: E/AndroidRuntime(28942):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4424)
08-27 23:17:44.692: E/AndroidRuntime(28942):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1992)
08-27 23:17:44.692: E/AndroidRuntime(28942):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1813)
08-27 23:17:44.692: E/AndroidRuntime(28942):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1113)
08-27 23:17:44.692: E/AndroidRuntime(28942):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4481)
08-27 23:17:44.692: E/AndroidRuntime(28942):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
08-27 23:17:44.692: E/AndroidRuntime(28942):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
08-27 23:17:44.692: E/AndroidRuntime(28942):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
08-27 23:17:44.692: E/AndroidRuntime(28942):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
08-27 23:17:44.692: E/AndroidRuntime(28942):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
08-27 23:17:44.692: E/AndroidRuntime(28942):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-27 23:17:44.692: E/AndroidRuntime(28942):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-27 23:17:44.692: E/AndroidRuntime(28942):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
08-27 23:17:44.692: E/AndroidRuntime(28942):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-27 23:17:44.692: E/AndroidRuntime(28942):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-27 23:17:44.692: E/AndroidRuntime(28942):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
08-27 23:17:44.692: E/AndroidRuntime(28942):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
08-27 23:17:44.692: E/AndroidRuntime(28942):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The error also points to the second line below, i tried to trace the problem with no success:

```
if (v == null) {
            **v = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.item_list_offers, null);**
        }else{
            super.getItemView(offer, v, parent);
        }
```

Comment: Your `getContext()` returns null.

Comment: any suggestions? as this occurs only when switching between two fragments fast.